# Gatling. Рандомное значение в симуляции

Tags: нагрузочное-тестирование, gatling

Я пытаюсь провести нагрузочное тестирование с помощью `Gatling`.

В теле симуляции я создаю сущность рест запросом в системе. Эта система предполагает, что при создании сущности, ее `id` должен быть не выдан БД а передан в запросе(Таким образом предполагается, что id заранее известен).

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Тот самый `id` я генерю рандомом. Так как симуляция запускает несколько запросов примерно в одно и то-же время, то семя рандома у каждых примерно 15-ти запусков оказывается одинаковым. Соответственно у них генерится одинаковый `id`, и 14 из каждых 15-ти запросов падают.

Вот код моей симуляции:

```
class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {
  val httpConf = http
    .baseUrls("http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081")

  val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation")
    .exec(
      http("Create entity")
        .post("/v1/api/entity")
        .header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
       .body{
          val id = new Random().nextInt(Int.MaxValue) + 1  // Вот в этой строке генерится одно и то же
                                                           // число для одновременных запусков 
          StringBody(s"""{"id":$id, "name":"${UUID.randomUUID()}"}""")
       }
       .check(jsonPath("$..id").ofType[Int].saveAs("eid"))
    )

  setUp(scn.inject(heavisideUsers(4).during(1 second)).protocols(httpConf))
}
```

Как можно сделать "настоящий" рандом в симуляции?
Или как вариант, как можно заставить `Gatling` делать паузы между запросами, чтоб каждый получал разное семя рандома?
Или любой другой способ, который поможет решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на просторах [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557649/gatling-scala-random-string-for-every-concurrent-user):
Можно использовать [feeder](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/):

```
class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {
  val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map(
    "id" -> (new Random().nextInt(Int.MaxValue) + 1),
    "name" -> UUID.randomUUID()
  ))

  val httpConf = http
    .baseUrls("http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081")

  val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation")
    .feed(feeder)
    .exec(
      http("Create entity")
       .post("/v1/api/entity")
       .header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
       .body(
          StringBody("""{"id":${id}, "name":"${name}"}""")
       )
       .check(jsonPath("$..id").ofType[Int].saveAs("eid"))
    )

  setUp(scn.inject(heavisideUsers(4).during(1 second)).protocols(httpConf))
}
```

Таким образом рандом прекрасно работает.